# Hot to save html file only from R and htmlwidgets?

Tags: javascript, r, heatmaply

I an using `R` to draw heatmap. `Heatmaply` and `htmlwidget` were installed. Fox example i exec following code:

```
library("htmlwidgets")
library("heatmaply")
heatmaply(mtcars) %>% saveWidget(file="test.html")
```

This always generate a test.html file and a test_files folder, but i  want the test.html only. I try `saveWidget(file="test.html",,selfcontained=TRUE)`. This just place the js library in the test.html, making test.html too big.

Comment: If you want a functioning heatmap, you need to save the libraries either in the html file itself or in the library folder.

Comment: notice that heatmaply now offers the file argument to save your heatmaply as html or png files.

Answer (score 2):

Use `self-contained=FALSE` to create plain HTML and a seperate folder, then use `system` to remove that folder:

```
heatmaply(mtcars) %>% 
  saveWidget(file="test.html", selfcontained = FALSE)
system('rm -r test_files')
```

Just be careful you don't have a folder named x_files, where x is the name of your plot output!

Comment: This lost the whole purpose of `selfcontatined` and the library folder and is not a solution. The html may not work if copied to other place.

Comment: Can you please take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65606653/r-saving-multiple-html-widgets-together thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A simpler solution is available in the recent version of heatmaply, simply use:

```
library("heatmaply")
heatmaply(mtcars, file="test.html")
```

Comment: Can you please take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65606653/r-saving-multiple-html-widgets-together thanks!