# R: Error in as.vector(x, "character"): cannot coerce type 'externalptr' to vector of type 'character'

Tags: html, r, image, widget, imagemagick

I am using the R programming language. I am trying to combine a HTML file and a JPG Image file together.

My code looks something like this:

```
library(plotly)
library(shiny)
library(magick)

#create widget_1
widget_1 = plot_ly(iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, type = "histogram", nbinsx = 20)

#upload some jpg image from your computer into R
my_image = image_read("my_image.jpg")

doc <- htmltools::tagList(
  div(widget_1, style = "float:left;width:50%;"),
  div(my_image,style = "float:left;width:50%;")
  
)

htmltools::save_html(html = doc, file = "C://Users//Me//Desktop//combined_file.html")
```

However, this code produces the following error:

```
Error in as.vector(x, "character"): cannot coerce type 'externalptr' to vector of type 'character'
```

Is it possible to save html and jpg files together in R? Or is this simply not possible?
Has anyone ever tried do this before?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can put this in R Markdown and knit it as HTML to get the output in one HTML file.

````
---
title: "temp"
output: html_document
---


```{r, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(plotly)
library(shiny)
library(magick)


widget_1 = plot_ly(iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, type = "histogram", nbinsx = 20)

#upload some jpg image from your computer into R
my_image = image_read("try.png")
```

```{r, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE, fig.height=3}
widget_1
```

```{r, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE, out.width = "600px"}
my_image
```
````

This generates HTML file as :

[image]